# somebody help me how to bind a function to a dom async

Tags: javascript

1. My first js file content:

   ```
   (function(){
       var html = '<div class="wrapper"><a class="test">111</a></div>'
       var app = document.getElementById('app');
       setTimeout(function(){
               app.innerHTML = html;
       },10)
   })()
   ```
2. My secondjs file content:

   ```
   var app = document.getElementById('app');
   app.addEventListener('click',function(e){
       console.log(e.target);
       e.target.addEventListener('click',function(){
           alert(111)
       })
   });
   ```
3. Dom:

   ```
   <div id="app"></div>
   ```

The question is how can I bind a function with dom 'test' by javascript, without Event commissioned. My English is not very good, hope you can understand and help me resolve this problem.

Comment: `setTimeout` requires a second parameter (number of milliseconds to wait before executing the function passed as the first parameter).

Comment: Where is your HTML element with the ID of `app`? Does it exist at this point of execution? If not, then the DOM will not have that element and JS will not be able to find it

Comment: `var app = document.getElementById('app');` is not necessary. Elements with `id` can per default be accessed using their id as a Javascript global variable.

Comment: <div id="app"></div>

Comment: just one element

Answer (score 0):

An old-school solution is set `onclick` handler directly on your `a` tag.

```js
(function(){
    var html = '<div class="wrapper"><a onclick="testClicked(event)" class="test">111</a></div>'
    var app = document.getElementById('app');
    setTimeout(function(){
            app.innerHTML = html;
    },10)
})()
function testClicked(e){
  alert(111);
}
```

```html
<div id= 'app'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setTimeout` to fix asynchronous loading issues. HTML5 parsing is asynchronous, and timing of when the `setTimeout` callback is invoked can be unpredictable. The [`DomContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event allows you to execute code when the document is ready in the order you specify:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var html = '<div class="wrapper"><a class="test">111</a></div>'
    var app = document.getElementById('app');
    app.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Notice the anonymous function is **not** immediately invoked using an IIFE and is instead called as an event handler. Listeners added to the same node are executed in the order they were added. If the second script is always loaded synchronously after the first, you can add a second event listener in the second file to find the `.test` element and add a click handler to it:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var app = document.getElementById('app');
    app.querySelector("a.test").addEventListener('click',function(e){
         alert(111);
    });
});
```

This approach is an example and assumes that the JavaScript file structure presented in the question is the most suitable for the app - there will always be other ways of doing the same thing.

---

Run this snippet for a demonstration (does not use external script files):

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var html = '<div class="wrapper"><a class="test">111</a></div>'
    var app = document.getElementById('app');
    app.innerHTML = html;
});
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var app = document.getElementById('app');
    app.querySelector("a.test").addEventListener('click',function(e){
         alert(111);
    });
  });
</script>
```